# How to yield from within an inner function in Python, Or, How to convert a loop to a generator, without directly calling yield?

Tags: python, stream, generator, yield

Consider

```
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

for n in gen():
    print(n)
```

prints

> ```
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```

---

Now, assume I have `data_source(foo)` that can take any function `foo`. It iterates on its own, and performs `foo` on what the iterator returns.

```
def foo(n: int):
    print(n)

def data_source(foo):
    for i in range(5):
        foo(i)

data_source(foo)
```

prints

> ```
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```

---

I want to convert `data_source` into a generator **without changing `data_source`**.

Can do whatever to `foo`, and can wrap `data_source` as much as required.

I want  something like

```
def foo(n: int):
    yield n

def data_source(foo):
    for i in range(5):
        foo(i)

for i in data_source(foo):
    print(i)
```

which obviously fails with

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

---

**Can a loop be converted to a generator via a callback, withtout touching the data_source itself?**

Comment: You need `looper` to `yield` for it to be consumed by the `for` loop. Otherwise, it implicitly returns `None` after completing its entire for loop in one go

Comment: @C.Nivs I know that. I was asking if there is a workaround or magic decorations that break execution somehow.

Comment: I assume patching the whole function with the decorater is not what you want?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Can you do it? it is what I want. `looper` has to remain the source of data.

Comment: EDIT: `looper` changed to `data_source` for clarity.

Comment: I guess the question boils down to: Can a loop be converted to a generator of what, exactly? `print` doesn't return anything, neither does `foo` or your `looper`, so I'm assuming you mean "How can I capture stdout?"

Comment: @C.Nivs it is true that they don't return anything. Not all generators do. `yield` can return nothing (and really return `None`). I am trying to break and return flow of `data_source`, controlled from `foo`. just like `for i in range(5): yield`. Nothing is returned, but control stops and returns upon `next`.